# How to create new database connection in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions

I need to create a new database connection(session) to avoid an unexpected commit from a MySql procedure in my django transaction. How to set up it in django?

I have tried to duplicate the database configuration in setting file. It worked for me but it seems not a good solution. See my code for more detail.

```
@classmethod
def get_sequence_no(cls, name='', enable_transaction=False):
    """
        return the sequence no for the given key name
    """
    if enable_transaction:
        valobj = cls.objects.using('sequence_no').raw("call sp_get_next_id('%s')" % name)
        return valobj[0].current_val
    else:
        valobj = cls.objects.raw("call sp_get_next_id('%s')" % name)
        return valobj[0].current_val
```

Does anyone know how to use a custom database connection to call the procedure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a look at the `django.db` module, you can see that `django.db.connection` is a proxy for `django.db.connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]` and `django.db.connections` is an instance of `django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler`.

Putting this together, you should be able to get a new connection like this:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, load_backend
    

def create_connection(alias=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS):
    connections.ensure_defaults(alias)
    connections.prepare_test_settings(alias)
    db = connections.databases[alias]
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    return backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
```

Note that this function will open a new connection every time it is called and you are responsible for closing it. Also, the APIs it uses are probably considered internal and might change without notice.

To close the connection, it should be enough to call `.close()` on the object return by the `create_connection` function:

```
conn = create_connection()
# do some stuff
conn.close()
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, just wondering, is there a snippet anywhere for closing such a connection? Do we have to switch the connection back to the default after using this?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I've expanded my answer

Comment: Ah, perfect! :) As easy as that, really appreciate you spending the time to expand on that.

Answer (score 3):

With modern Django you can just do:

```py
from django.db import connections

new_connection = connections.create_connection('default')
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Once you have the new_connection, how do you run things using that new_connection? Using the above code gets the database but any code below it will use the default database.