# User self-hosted Database in Django

Tags: python, django, database, file-storage

I have a Django project where the users can connect their own database as well as static file storage for security purposes. For example: when a user will signup into our system, they will ask for a database and a file storage address and credentials. After that, all the data for this user will store in his self-hosted Database as well as files also.

I already checked the [multi-database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/) feature in Django but I guess it's not helpful for me

Comment: "_for security purposes_", I would consider this way somewhat incorrect in that case? If the user is so concerned about security why should they share _their_ database credentials with you? Let us say your database gets compromised, that in the end will result in their database also getting compromised since you would be storing their db credentials in your db...

Comment: Yaa, You are right, there is a loophole but what if I store the user database credentials as hashed data same as user password, So if my database got compromised then also user database will be secure. what do you think @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Hashes are one way only, i.e. you cannot get back the original value. Then the question becomes how will you connect to their database? Let's say instead of hashing you use encryption, then what is the benefit? You could have encrypted all the user's data instead of using so many databases. In the end your idea only increases vulnerabilities rather than decreasing them...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to:

- Use your own database as init and for common data
- For customer sensitive data, store on that remote DB, and for that remote DB, connect using this: [How to create new database connection in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733112/how-to-create-new-database-connection-in-django)